# Android - How to pass data from service, when service is not started from activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

Have been searching for answers, but still didnt find a good solution. Problem is, my background service starts depending on network availability and not from the main activity (I dont want to change that). I know you can simply start activity one more time from intent and pass specific data, but how to make some sort of global listener in the main activity, so it can receive data from service and update GUI without restarting. Btw I know you can set intent flags, however it doesnt really work that well...

Comment: Are you saying you want to start the `Activity` from the `Service`? Don't do that. Your question is unclear please explain more clearly. What does your `Service` do? What does your `Activity` do?

Comment: Service handles sync between SqLite and remote database over the net. It is immediately run when the internet becomes available and quite independent from activity. I dont need to run activity again from the service, I just need to notify it if the sync is successful while its running.

Comment: But what if the `Activity` isn't running? In that case you can't notify it of anything. Instead your `Service` should simply keep track of sync success / failure information and your `Activity` should bind to the `Service` when it starts. If you want real-time updates to the `Activity` then use an inner `BroadcastReceiver` and send local broadcasts from the `Service` to the receiver.

Comment: use bindService in your Activity

Comment: Service checks if activity is running before sending any data. Will try the bindService option.

Comment: see local service pattern for using a connection Binder

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this thing using Broadcast Receiver OR handler. Just register receiver and pass data to BR from service and implement that Receiver to Activity, inside onReceive() method of BR you will get data. Another way is using Handler, using Message you can send data to Activity when you particular event fires.

Reference Link [here](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/11/pass-data-from-service-to-activity.html)